# How do I access a SQL database from a different activity?

Tags: android, sql

I have created a SQL Database and the helper for it.  I instantiate the database:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

in the onCreate  method of my main activity class.

Now how do I access this database from other activities? do I need to instantiate it again? if so, where and what parameters do I use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In each class u need to call the db to create it `DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);` and then `db.open();` and after that `db.yourMethodQuery` to call the method you have in your DatabaseHelper.

Better thing to do is just to have a global variable of `DatabaseHelper db;` and call it in on create to instantiate it `db = new DatabaseHelper(this);` And then you can call db.something anywhere in the class

Comment: do I do this in the oncreate method of each clase? or where

Comment: It depends. But in onCreate is the most usual thing to do.

Comment: And btw, your database helper should be `synchronized` to avoid concurrency. That's not a must, but is recommended !

Comment: In onCreate its like it will instantiate the database for you before the activity shows up, and after the activity appears then it will acceps any new command to call the database with any of your actions. Actions be :button clicks or anything that calls the db

Comment: @antonislambrianides - Just to Clarify what Antonis means, it does not mean that the DB connection will happen before an `Activity` "exists", it's just before the activity is `VISIBLE` or in the foreground.

Comment: Yes. onCreate happens before onStart. onStart is where things get visible. So onCreate is called to create things, like databases, the buttons, textfields, spinners etc. And after that onStart is called and makes evything visible to the user

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton that only creates a connection when you use it.
Just need to call it like this: `DatabaseHelper db = new Database(this);`

Try this:

```
public class Database {

   private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

   public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(INSERT_CLASS_OF_THIS this) {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new DatabaseHelper(this);
      }
      return instance;
   }

}
```